# Representation of Poincaré group and quantum field

Tags: quantum-field-theory, special-relativity, representation-theory, lie-algebra, poincare-symmetry

How can we understand the quantum field $$\phi(x) = \int \frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^3\sqrt{2E}} ( a_p e^{-ipx}+ a^\dagger_p e^{ipx}) ,$$ where  $ a_p$ and $a^\dagger_p$ are creation annihilation operators,  in QFT, as a representation of the Poincaré Group?

As I understand it, you have to find a generator of one of the symmetries of the Poincaré group and exponentiate it in order to have a (unitary) representation of the Poincaré group. For example $U(t)= e^{-itH}$ for the representation of the time translation. So it has nothing to do with this quantum field.

Comment: What do you mean "understanding" the quantum field as a representation of the Poincaré group? Are you asking how the field transforms under a Poincaré transformation? Can you try to be more specific? Possibly related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/127989/50583, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/174898/50583

Comment: I am a beginner in QFT, my teacher said that if you build a state $\mid p >= \sqrt{2E} a^\dagger_p \mid 0>$ then $U(\Lambda) =  \sqrt{2E} a^\dagger_p $ is a unitary representation of Lorentz. So first, I don't understand that. And he goes further by saying that $\phi(x)$ is a representation of Lorentz. (he said Lorentz, not Poincaré by the way, sorry).

Comment: Closely related https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/799610/226902