# How is a tensor operator defined in terms of commutators?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, angular-momentum, tensor-calculus, definition

If $J_i$ represent the angular momentum operators, then a scalar operator $S$ (rank-0 tensor) is defined as an operator which satisfies $$[S,J_i]=0$$ for $i=1,2,3$.

$A_i$ is a vector (rank-1 tensor) operator, if it satisfies $$[J_i,A_j]=i\hbar\epsilon_{ijk}A_k$$

How does a rank-2 tensor operator defined in terms of commutators?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/73532/2451

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given
\begin{align}
\hat L_\pm \vert \ell m\rangle &= \sqrt{(\ell\mp m)(\ell\pm m+1)}\vert \ell,m\pm 1\rangle\, ,\\
\hat  L_0 \vert \ell m\rangle &= m \vert \ell m\rangle
\end{align}
then by definition $\hat T^{(\ell)}_m$ commutes as
\begin{align}
[\hat  L_\pm, \hat T^{(\ell)}_m]&=\sqrt{(\ell\mp m)(\ell\pm m+1)}\,\hat T^{(\ell)}_{m\pm 1}\, ,\\
[\hat L_0, \hat T^{(\ell)}_m]&=m\,\hat T^{(\ell)}_{m}\, ,
\end{align}
valid for any $\ell,m$.